# Add a new row totaling unique column values in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe from Pandas.

**Input**

```
>>> df
       address value     number     total
0      address a         8
1      address a         10
2      address a         12
3      address b         4
4      address b         7
5      address c         15
```

I want to be able to add a new row below rows that contain unique values totaling them.

**Output**

```
>>> df
       address value    number     total
0      address a        8
1      address a        10
2      address a        12
3                                   30
4      address b        4
5      address b        7
6                                   10
7      address c        15
8                                   15
```

I am able to group and sum the unique values with df.groupby. Is there a way to add those values to a total column on a new row below? Perhaps there is a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously is used new column filled by repated values:

```
df['total'] = df.groupby('address value')['number'].transform('sum')
print (df)
  address value  number  total
0     address a       8     30
1     address a      10     30
2     address a      12     30
3     address b       4     11
4     address b       7     11
5     address c      15     15
```

But is is possible, by:

```
d = dict(zip(range(df['address value'].nunique()), 
             df['address value'].drop_duplicates(keep='last').index))
df1 = df.groupby('address value')['number'].sum().reset_index(name='total').rename(d)
df1['address value'] = ''


df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
df[['number','total']] = df[['number','total']].astype('Int64')
print (df)
  address value  number  total
0     address a       8   <NA>
1     address a      10   <NA>
2     address a      12   <NA>
3                  <NA>     30
4     address b       4   <NA>
5     address b       7   <NA>
6                  <NA>     11
7     address c      15   <NA>
8                  <NA>     15
```